# Add a template suggestion with highest-priority in custom module

Tags: 8, theming

It's easy to override an existing template in custom theme using one of the template suggestions or just by copying the desired template file and past it under custom theme templates directory.

But whenever you have an overriding template in your custom theme, and you desire to override that template in custom module you can do it by adding a new hook suggestion using `hook_theme_suggestions_hook()` or `hook_theme_suggestions_alter()` hooks, the problem is how to informe Drupal that the new added suggestion by the custom module should has a highest-priority than the one defined in custom theme, especially when the custom theme already used the existing highest-priority suggestion.

One of the proposed solution is using `hook_theme_registry_alter()`, but this is the wrong approach because  it will always force the theme system to use the template declared in the custom module templates directory.

Is there an approach to have a full control on managing suggestions priorities ?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question. You've already explained and answered everything really good yourself. Do you want to make something "unthemeable"? In that case you could use e.g. an `inline-template`

Comment: I just want to know how could I add a theme suggestion with highest-priority in a custom module, how to control the priority of new added suggestions, that's it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I want that the node--article.html.twig of my custom module templates been used with highest priority than my current custom theme node--article.html.twig. It would make more sens.